# How to remove all characters after 3rd colon?

Tags: c#, substring, indexof

I have a date time span but currently a user can type in `12:00:00:00` and I get this error:

> SqlDbType.Time overflow.  Value '12:00:00:00' is out of range.  Must be between 00:00:00.0000000 and 23:59:59.9999999.

So to stop them doing this I thought it would be easier if I strip all characters after the third colon. How do I do this?

Comment: You'd be better off restricting the users to only be able to enter valid data in the first place, something like two textboxes clamped to 2 digits only. Some pre submit validation. A bit of js can link the textboxes together so the user doesn't need to select the second when typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `12:00:00.00` not `12.00:00:00`

Note fullstop in yours.

Try

```
        string badtimes = "12:00:00:00";
        string goodtimes = badtimes.Substring(0, badtimes.LastIndexOf(":")); // 12:00:00
```

Also check out [SqlDbType.Time and TimeSpan incompatibility](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/537c8c14-09da-4ddd-b1e4-330340ddd7b1/)

Comment: sorry i have tested it with both

Comment: OK added a little snip for you

Answer (score 1):

The dot in your string is not placed correctly:
 `12.00:00:00` must be `12:00:00.00`

Comment: the user types in 12:00:00:00 no dots are allowed in front end

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
String time = "12:00:00:00";
        string[] parts = time.Split(new char [] {':'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string correctFormating = String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}.{3}",parts);
```